# SDL libraries are missing

Tags: make, sdl

```
~/vidmodel/wvsn-model-omnetpp-v4/geometry/Triangle.o ~/vidmodel/wvsn-model-omnetpp-v4/geometry/Polygon.o ~/vidmodel/wvsn-model-omnetpp-v4/geometry/triangulation.o -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--whole-archive -lSDL -lpng -ljpeg -lz -lSDL_image -Wl,--no-whole-archive -L"/home/sreeram/omnetpp-4.2.2/lib/gcc" -L"/home/sreeram/omnetpp-4.2.2/lib" -loppmain -u _cmdenv_lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -loppcmdenv -loppenvir -loppsim -ldl -lstdc++ 
 /usr/bin/ld: 

cannot find -lSDL
/usr/bin/ld: 

cannot find -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljpeg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_image
collect2: ld returned 1 exit
```

can any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the development files. These are usually called libfoo-dev, for example libjpeg8-dev or libsdl2-dev.

See this post for more info: http://who-t.blogspot.com/2014/05/configure-fails-with-no-package-foo.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Who-t+%28Who-T%29